# Data fingerprint using polynomial and Schwartz-Zippel Lemma

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, finite-field, checksum

I'm working on a protocol and am looking for a way to fingerprint a set of elements. All elements are evenly distributed across a finite field that is integers modulus $2^{256}$.

Assume I have a set of elements $[v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3]$, and a strong random value $R$ (also in the field).

I construct a hash like this $H = v_0 + v_1R + v_2R^2 + v_3R^3$

Can [Schwartz–Zippel lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/schwartz-zippel-lemma/) be applied to this? Like the odds of another set $[v_0, \ldots v_3]$ having hash $H$ are equal to the odds of another set $[v_0, \ldots v_3]$ being the zero polynomial? e.g. $n/|F| = 4/2^{256}$

As a followup, could I represent the algorithm like this: $(v_0 + R)*(v_1 + R)*(v_2 + R)*(v_3 + R)$? Would this be functionally the same (even though it reduces to different coefficients)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Integers modulo $2^{256}$ form a _ring_, not a _field_. Argument: $2$ and $4$ haves no multiplicative inverses. $\mathbb F_{2^{256}}$ is a field, but is not integers modulo $2^{256}$; rather, it's elements can be described as polynomials with binary coefficients and degree less than 256, and it's multiplication is polynomial multiplication followed by reduction modulo some degree-256 irreducible polynomial with binary coefficients. $\mathbb F_{2^{256}-189}$ and $\mathbb F_{2^{256}+297}$ are fields that are integers modulo a prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integers modulo $2^{256}$ are not a field but a ring with identity where every number divisible by $2$ is a zero divisor. See [this question and its answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186074/can-schwartz-zippel-be-formulated-for-commutative-rings-instead-of-fields) for conditions on applying Schwartz-Zippel (SZ) to rings. There are technical issues to be addressed, however you may just be happy with using the *finite field* $\mathbb{F}_{2^{256}}$ where the SZ lemma holds.

Your $H(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)=v_0+v_1 R+ v_2 R^2+ v_3 R^3$ *being a multivariate linear polynomial in the $v_i$* (thanks to @DanielS for catching my error)  has degree 1 and thus has at most 1 root1 in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{256}}$ so if you define the fingerprint of $V=\{v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ as $H(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ the probability that another 4 element set
$V='\{v_0',v_1',v_2',v_3'\}$ will have the same fingerprint where $V'\neq V$ is $\leq 1/2^{256}.$

If you formulate your fingerprinting by using the second polynomial
$$
\Pi_{i=0}^3 (v_i+R)
$$
this gives collision probability $4/2^{256}$ since it is actually of total degree 4 due to the $v_0 v_1 v_2 v_4$ term, while the first polynomial was degree 1. In practice, for such small sets, the difference in probability is negligible but for more sizeable sets it would be a problem.

Comment: $H(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is degree 1 in the $v_i$ and hence the probability of collision is $1/2^{256}$. We can check this by fixing $v_1’$, $v_2’$, $v_3’$ and letting $v_0’$ run over all possible values. (I’m assuming that $R$ is the same for all $H$, but even if it isn’t we can beat SZ in this case).